# Рекурсия. Как происходит вход в условие

Tags: c#, .net, рекурсия

Имеется такая функция, которая вызывает сама себя, то есть рекурсивная. 
Допустим n = 5. Нужно посчитать сумму элементов, которые отобразятся на консоль (но это просто к слову).

Сначала вроде все понятно. Последовательность будет такой 5 4 3 2 1 0. Вот дальше не могу понять, в дебаге это выглядит так так - 0 по условию не подходит и естественно в тело if не попадает, но по достижению последней скобки, в обратную сторону идет(то есть выполнение функции начинается не сначала, а с конца) **На фото последовательность вызовов** и каким-то образом попадает в if и n = 1. Как это происходит? Я не могу понять

```
static public void F(int n)
    {
        Console.Write(n + " ");
        if (n > 0)
        {
            F(n - 1);
            F(n - 3);
        }
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

В этом суть рекурсии, она вызывает сама себя, потом возвращает управление, но в то место, где была вызвана

Поэтому получается, что сначала функция уходит вглубь и доходит до `n` равное `0`, потом потом возвращает управление предыдущей функции, где `n` ещё было равно единице и заходит в функцию `F(n-3);` где становится равным `-2`, потом возвращает значение функции, где `n` равно единице, потом происходит выход и из неё, где она возвращает управление функции, где n равно `2` и т.д.

Хороший способ понять рекурсию обойти дерево в глубину.